# Code erroring upon editing, but fine when building

Tags: xcode, macos, swift

All of my code is fine when I build/run the application; whenever I edit it, up comes a lot of error messages with errors such as

`"Use of undeclared type '-object type-'"`

as you can see in the picture below. From what I have observed, it happens after `@NSApplicationMain` but if I remove it, the code errors for good. Any insights on why this happens?

[image]

It also terminates itself when I run it with the error `"an uncaught exception was raised"`. The app gets **terminated on line 29** where the AppDelegate class is defined. [I put the error log in a GitHub Gist here.](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Usering/da6bfe0b5469084d77c6/raw/bf119307481a4752e929571a5cd5d218c3af9944/gistfile1.txt)

Answer (score 0):

I was on an old beta of Xcode 6.1.